# Installing R packages on Amazon Linux EC2 instance

Tags: r, amazon-ec2, rselenium

I am learning to use RSelenium in an EC2 instance, and I found this handy guide on doing so - https://rpubs.com/grahamplace/rselenium-ec2 - however the guide focuses on an Ubuntu instance and I am using an Amazon Linux Instance. In order to install RSelenium, the guide says I must externally (outside of R but ssh'd into my EC2 instance) install the packages xml (XML i think, case sensitive) and RCurl. The guide's relevant lines of code are:

```
sudo apt-get install r-cran-xml
sudo apt-get install r-cran-RCurl
```

however, since I'm in an Amazon Linux instance, I tried:

```
sudo yum install r-cran-xml
sudo yum install r-cran-RCurl
```

for which I get the following error:

```
No package r-cran-RCurl available.
Error: Nothing to do
```

Note: I was successful in installing R on my machine (my instance), and I am able to simply type R to launch R in the EC2 instance.

Note2: install.packages('XML') and install.packages('RCurl') with R launched do not work either.

Any help appreciated with this, thanks!

Comment: I am not a professional with Amazon EC2...and often I am angry at it. But for me, the issue with installing from R directly was permissions assigned to R. If you give yourself read, write execute permissions for R and for the folder with the libraries you are installing that might help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the amazon linux `R` package has a different name:

```
sudo yum install -y R
```

then you tried (in `R`) `install.packages(c('XML','RCurl'))`, but the installation failed.

as you discovered and describe in the comment below, you needed to install an additional amazon linux package, `libxml2-devel`, in order to `install.packages('XML')` successfully.

Comment: surprisingly, install.packages('RCurl') worked, but install.packages('XML') didn't. here's the error message for the latter:

...

...

checking for xml2-config... no

Cannot find xml2-config

ERROR: configuration failed for package ‘XML’

* removing ‘/home/ec2-user/R/x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu-library/3.3/XML’


The downloaded source packages are in

 ‘/tmp/RtmpZnPYSq/downloaded_packages’

Warning message:

In install.packages("XML") :

  installation of package ‘XML’ had non-zero exit status

Comment: formatting is messy on that - relevant part is (checking for xml2-config... no Cannot find xml2-config) - interestingly enough, the downloaded source package still exists at ‘/tmp/RtmpZnPYSq/downloaded_packages’

Answer (score 1):

this is what I get when I run `sudo yum install -y R`

No package R available.
Error: Nothing to do

R is available in Amazon Linux Extra topic "R3.4"

To use, run
`sudo amazon-linux-extras install R3.4`

Learn more at
https://aws.amazon.com/amazon-linux-2/faqs/#Amazon_Linux_Extras